# The cyclomatic complexity exceeded the defined limit (cost '30'). Your template should be refactored

Tags: angular, tslint

I am getting the following error while running the "ts lint" comment in my Angular application.

> The cyclomatic complexity exceeded the defined limit (cost '30'). Your template should be refactored.

This is showing all the places where and all I used *ngIf in my application.

Comment: pease give examples of conditions used with *ngIf

Answer (score 3):

> Cyclomatic complexity is a code metric which indicates the level of
> complexity in a function. High cyclomatic complexity indicates
> confusing code which may be prone to errors or difficult to modify.
>
> It’s better to have smaller, single-purpose functions with
> self-documenting names.

The following statements and expressions contribute to cyclomatic complexity:

```
* catch
* if and ? :
* || and && due to short-circuit evaluation
* for, for in and for of loops
* while and do while loops
* case clauses that contain statements
```

SRC : [cyclomatic-complexity](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/cyclomatic-complexity/)

---

Thus, you should refactor your code and split your functions (or templates in your case), where these errors occur, to more smaller chunks (~components in your case).

---

**FYI : TSLint has been deprecated as of 2019, check their [site](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) for more details.**

Comment: It is showing error for the template where ever I used *ngIf. Is it any possible way to resolve this?

Comment: @SelvaAjitha add `"cyclomatic-complexity": false` in tslint config file